# TypeError: create_purple() takes 0 positional arguments but 2 were given

Tags: python, class, python-3.x, arguments, typeerror

I am brand new to Python programming and trying to make this program work.

I have made this program work by using "if" and "else" statements only, however, I wanted to make this same program with the method below. When I run the program I keep getting an error "TypeError: create_purple() takes 0 positional arguments but 2 were given" and I cannot figure out why.

Here is my code:

```
#*******************************************************************************************
#
# This program will take any two primary colors and create a secondary color.
#
# Primary colors are:
# Blue, Red, Yellow
# 
# Secondary colors are:
# Green, Orange, Purple
#

#Clear the screen
import os
os.system('cls') 

RED = "red"
BLUE = "blue"
YELLOW = "yellow"

def main():
    print ('\n')
    # Tell the user the objective of the program.
    print ('*****************************************************************************')
    print ('*****************************************************************************')
    print ('\n')
    print ('The objective of this program is to create a secondary color from two primary')
    print ('colors. When asked, choose two primary colors (Red, Blue, or Yellow) to create')
    print ('a secondary color ')

    # Choose your colors
    color1 = input('Enter your first primary color: ')
    color2 = input('Enter your second primary color: ')

    # Determine the secondary color
    if color1 == RED and color2 == BLUE:
    create_purple(color1,color2)


def create_purple():

    # Determine the color is purple
    if color1 == RED and color2 == BLUE:
        print ('\n')
        print ('You have made the color.... Purple ')
    else:
        if color1 == BLUE and color2 == RED:
            print ('\n')
            print ('You have made the color.... Purple ')

# Call the main function
main()
```

Comment: I hate when I do this - I figured it out just after I posted the question. I needed to insert "color1,color2" into the def create_purple(): line. It should read... def create_purple(color1,color2):

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling create_purple with 2 arguments, yet your definition (def) has 0 arguments.

Simply update the definition:

```
def create_purple(color1,color2):
```