# Function to find vowels in a word?

Tags: python

I have a problem where I have to use a function to output the vowels in a word and output how many vowels there are. I just took a computing course at the local college and am new to this whole thing and its going over my head a bit.

I tried but this is what i got when I ran it:

```
TypeError: vowel() takes 0 positional arguements but 1 was given
```

My code:

```
def vowel ():
  array = []
  counter = 0
  for i in word:
    if i in ("a","e","i","o","u"):
      counter+=1
      array.append(i)
  return (array, counter)

word = input("Enter your word")
function = vowel(word)
print(function)
```

Comment: Please wrap your code in the code tags.

Comment: Look, your function definition doesn't accept any argument, while inside `vowel(word)` you do send it an argument.

Comment: just change `def vowel ():` to `def vowel (word):`, your code works fine.

Comment: Same problem as [Python - TypeError: create\_purple() takes 0 positional arguments but 2 were given](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26144191/python-typeerror-create-purple-takes-0-positional-arguments-but-2-were-give)

Comment: http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/functions.html

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the error is simple.

When you define the function *Vowel*, It doesn't recieve any argument.

It should look like this:

```
def vowel (word):
```

Hope i can help you :D

Comment: thank you so much you really helped me out :)

Answer (score 1):

The number of arguments given in the function definition and function call should be same. In the function definition, you have written `def vowel():` but while calling `function = vowel(word)` you are providing an argument to the function. Hence it throws an error. You can modify it as:

```
def vowel(word):
   array = []
   counter = 0
   for i in word:
     if i in ("a","e","i","o","u"):
       counter+=1
       array.append(i)
   return (array, counter)

word = input("Enter your word")
function = vowel(word)
print(function)
```

Comment: thanks so much it works now

Answer (score 0):

In function definition, you forgot to provide `word`

```
def vowel (word):
  array = []
  counter = 0
  for i in word:
    if i in ("a","e","i","o","u"):
      counter+=1
      array.append(i)
  return (array, counter)


word = input("Enter your word")
function = vowel(word)
print(function)
```

To read more about Positional arguments see this post [Positional argument v.s. keyword argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9450656/positional-argument-v-s-keyword-argument)

Comment: simple mistake :) I feel like an idiot now but thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

The error is self explanatory.
You declared the function vowel to be seeded with 0 arguments.

```
def vowel ():
```

and you called it seeding it with one argument:

```
 function = vowel(word)
```

what you should have done is:

```
def vowel (word):
    array = []
    counter = 0
    for i in word:
        if i in ("a","e","i","o","u"):
        counter+=1
        array.append(i)
    return (array, counter)
```

Comment: thanks the program works well now

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function and then simple list comprehension:

```
def vowel(word):
   array = [i for i in word if i in ("a","e","i","o","u")]
   counter = len(array)
   return array, counter

word = input("Enter your word")
function = vowel(word)
print(function)
```

Comment: thank you lots the program works really well