# "TypeError: count() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given", what is wrong with the code

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to find no. of even and odd numbers from the list.

```
list = []


for i in range(5):
    lst = int(input("Enter the numbers: "))
    list.append(lst)
print(list)

even = 0
odd = 0
def count():
    for i in list:
        if list[i] % 2 == 0:
            even+=1
        else:
            odd+=1

    return even, odd
even,odd = count(list)
print('Even : {} and Odd : {}'.format(even,odd))
```

I'm getting an error:TypeError: count() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given. What does it mean?

Comment: `count(list):`,  or don't pass the argument if you already defined `list` in global scope, also don't use python keywords like `list` as a variable name, define `even` and `odd` in your function, and use `i` in the for loop for modulus check instead of `list[i]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: create\_purple() takes 0 positional arguments but 2 were given](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26144191/typeerror-create-purple-takes-0-positional-arguments-but-2-were-given)
Also, please don't use [builtin keywords or functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) as variable names (use `my_list` instead of `list`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your `count()` function set to take zero arguments. But then you passed an argument to it in the second to last line. Since you already have it set to count list, just change `count(list)` to `count()` in that line.